# Kubernetes minikube running in wsl Ubuntu exposes a service i cannot reach from win 10

Tags: docker, networking, windows-subsystem-for-linux, minikube

i was following a kubernetes tutorial for beginners (techworld with nana) with a win10 machine running docker. As i got troubles, i migrate to this config :

```
wsl -l -v
  NAME      STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu    Running         2
```

I install docker and run it by  `$ sudo service docker start`
Start minikube : `$minikube start --driver=docker --kubernetes-version=v1.18.0`
(not the last version because some pb between systemd and systemctl)

Everything was ok, i create a mongodb pod and a mongoexpress pod with ad hoc services:

```
plaurent$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
mongo-express-864c95f479-8gfxf        1/1     Running   2          23h
mongodb-deployment-58977cc4f5-k4r4h   1/1     Running   1          23h
plaurent$ kubectl get service
NAME                    TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes              ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP          23h
mongo-express-service   LoadBalancer   10.98.7.33       <pending>     8081:30000/TCP   23h
mongodb-service         ClusterIP      10.101.132.245   <none>        27017/TCP        23h
```

following tuto, i run :

```
/plaurent$ minikube service mongo-express-service
  Starting tunnel for service mongo-express-service.
  Opening service default/mongo-express-service in default browser...
  http://192.168.49.2:30000
❗  Because you are using a Docker driver on linux, the terminal needs to be open to run it.
```

On a second terminal wsl, i can reach this service with the following and it's ok.

```
plaurent$ curl http://192.168.49.2:30000
```

BUt i cannot do the same thing from the win10 and even a ping fails.

i start ip addr and get the following :

```
/plaurent$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 86:5b:79:bf:27:05 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: dummy0: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f2:bd:6f:41:f3:2d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:b5:ae:43 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.20.254.215/20 brd 172.20.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::215:5dff:feb5:ae43/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: tunl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
6: sit0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
7: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:eb:30:05:9a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: br-ecf9b5a8d792: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:0f:31:2f:71 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    **inet 192.168.49.1/24 brd 192.168.49.255 scope global br-ecf9b5a8d792**
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:fff:fe31:2f71/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
10: vethe8c97a5@if9: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-ecf9b5a8d792 state UP group default
    link/ether ee:d2:2d:f8:5b:4d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::ecd2:2dff:fef8:5b4d/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

i can see *inet 192.168.49.1/24 brd 192.168.49.255 scope global br-ecf9b5a8d792* close to the ip of service, but i don't know what it means and if this can help to solve the problem.
I'm not comfortable with networks , any help welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can do port forward of the services in cluster. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/